# Codeigniter RestFull Api Call Show Error on Postman

Tags: codeigniter

Its Baseurl of api call http://localhost/data_model/users/login when i run this in postman or browser its show me the error. My all links after data_model like data_model/a or data_model/b that are created in folders show me same error.

Error: {"status":false,"message":"Invalid Request","data":[],"auth_code":"100100"}

`

```
public function login() {
        $input = $this->validate_login();

        $user = $this->Users_model->login($input);
        if ($user) {
            if ($user['status'] == 1)
                return_data(false, 'Your Account Disabled', json_decode("{}"));
            else if ($user['status'] == 1)
                return_data(false, 'Account Deleted', json_decode("{}"));
            else {
                return_data(true, 'User authentication successful.', $user);
            }
        }
        return_data(false, 'Authentication Failed', json_decode("{}"));
    }
```

`

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';

require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';
```